# How do I diff 2 folders by file name, but just the beginning of the file names using zsh?

Tags: zsh, diff

So I have 2 folders with a lot of similar files, and the version is written in the filename, so what I wanna do is check if the beginning of the filename is the same (for example "sample-1.12" and "sample-1.13" should be treated as same). I just need to find files without a similar named file in the opposing folder.

The initial part of the filename to check ends at the first dash, underscore or square bracket.

Comment: You have to define the phrase `if the beginning of the filename is the same`. More specifically, where the beginning is ending (for example, at the first dash?).

Comment: @thanasisp the beginning ends at the first dash, underscore or square bracket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `${a:|b}` array-substraction operator:

```
dir1=/some/dir
dir2=/some/other/dir

a=($dir1/*[[_-]*(N:t)) # [t]ail of every file with at least one -, [ or _
b=($dir2/*[[_-]*(N:t))

a=(${a%%[[_-]*}) # strip [*, _* or -* suffix
b=(${b%%[[_-]*})

print -r in $dir1 and not in $dir2:
print -rC1 -- ${a:|b}
print -r in $dir2 and not in $dir1:
print -rC1 -- ${b:|a}
```